# laravel ssh2 exec command

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, exec

I'm trying to create something based on ssh2 connecting to my vps and then creating some files and running them with exec commands.

I already finished a bigger part which is creating a directory moving files from one directory to another now I need to do something like this

cd directory previously created

nohup ./samp03srv

but how can i do this with php ?

this is what i got so far

```
    $ssh = new SSH2($request->ip);

    if (!$ssh->login("root", "password"))
    {
        return back()->withErrors("Authentication failed! Please check your credentials!");
    }

    $randomNum = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 11);

    $src = $request->path;
    $dest = "/home/servers/$randomNum";

    $ssh->exec("cp -r $src $dest");
    $ssh->disconnect();
```

If you need more info please ask!